# Pass JQuery variable from function to document.ready

Tags: jquery, html

I'm having trouble passing my variables from one function into `document.ready` so that I can insert into my HTML.

If I define distance outside of the current `displayContent` function then it works, but I can't seem to get the value from inside that function into `document.ready`. I tried wrapping my `displayContent` function inside of `document.ready` but that didn't work either.

My code currently is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var distance;

function displayContent(json) {
        var len = json.feed.entry.length;
        var distance = json.feed.entry[0].gsx$todaydist.$t;
        var calso = json.feed.entry[0].gsx$todaycalso.$t;
        var calsi = json.feed.entry[0].gsx$todaycalsi.$t;               
}   


    $( document ).ready(function() {
            $(".distance").html(distance)
});
</script>
```

Comment: And how are you getting the JSON and calling the function, seems like you should call the function in the DOM ready handler and return the result or something ?

Comment: Seems like you haven't called the **displayContent()** function before setting its value **$(".distance").html(distance)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first impression is that you have declared distance variable twice rather than declaring it and assigning

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var distance;

function displayContent(json) {
        var len = json.feed.entry.length;
        distance = json.feed.entry[0].gsx$todaydist.$t;
        var calso = json.feed.entry[0].gsx$todaycalso.$t;
        var calsi = json.feed.entry[0].gsx$todaycalsi.$t;               
}   


    $( document ).ready(function() {
            $(".distance").html(distance)
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can't believe it was so simple! I couldn't even see the difference in your code at first... Thank you!